# "Variabilize" the ampersand (background a process)

Tags: bash, shell-script, variable, background-process

I want to know if there's a way to put the ampersand in a variable and still use it to send a process to the background.

This works:

```
BCKGRND=yes
if [ "$BCKGRND" = "yes" ]; then
    sleep 5 &
else
    sleep 5
fi
```

But wouldn't it be cool to accomplish those five lines with only one?  Like so:

```
BCKGRND='&'
sleep 5 ${BCKGRND}
```

But that doesn't work.  If BCKGRND isn't set it works - but when it is set it's interpreted it as a literal '&' and errors out.

Comment: after using the trailing ampersand, `echo $!` returns the PID

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's not possible to use a variable to background the call because variable expansion happens after the command-line is parsed for control operators (such as `&&` and `&`).

Yet another option would be to wrap the calls in a function:

```
mayberunbg() {
  if [ "$BCKGRND" = "yes" ]; then
    "$@" &
  else
    "$@"
  fi
}
```

... and then set the variable as needed:

```
$ BCKGRND=yes mayberunbg sleep 3
[1] 14137
$
[1]+  Done                    "$@"
# or
$ BCKGRND=yes
$ mayberunbg sleep 3
[1] 14203
$
[1]+  Done                    "$@"
$ BCKGRND=no mayberunbg sleep 3
# 3 seconds later
$
```

Comment: What, no `ed`? +1 anyway, this is the cleanest solution.

Comment: LOL @StephenKitt; now the gears are turning

Comment: I liked the eval answer for its simplicity but my actual real-world command I wanted to background was far too complicated with too many variables in it to be comfortable using eval.  @jeff-schaller gave the answer that pointed me in the direction I went.  Instead of a function, though, I put the entire command in a variable then used his if statement style to execute the command with or without the &.

Answer (score 11):

You can flip things and variabilise “foregrounding”:

```
FOREGROUND=fg
sleep 5 & ${FOREGROUND}
```

Set `FOREGROUND` to `true` or empty to run the process in the background. (Setting `FOREGROUND` to `true` to run in the background is admittedly confusing! Appropriate variable names are left as an exercise for the reader.)

Comment: that's nice but it won't work in a shell without job control (ie any script unless `set -m` was used).

Answer (score 8):

You would probably have to use `eval`:

```
eval "sleep 5" "$BCKGRND"
```

`eval` causes the shell to re-evaluate the arguments given. A literal `&` would therefore be interpreted as `&` at the end of a command and not as an argument to the command, putting the command in the background.

Comment: A answer containing `eval` should  contain a warning, that this should be handles with care. See e.g. this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17529221/7369280).

Comment: I don't get what the problem is with `"$BCKGRND"` evaluating to an empty argument.

Comment: @Ralf absolutely irrelevant *in this case*. There's nothing special about eval -- you can execute commands via arithmetic expansions, for instance. Maybe there should be such a warning against using bash (or any similar shell) at all ;-)

Comment: @mosvy Well, it depends on what the command is doing.  In the case of `sleep 5`, an extra empty argument may not matter. In the case of some other command or user-supplied script, it may.

Comment: @Kusalananda `eval` will join its arguments with spaces before doing the actual eval. Just try it: `eval printf "'{%s}\n'" foo "" "" ""`. `eval foo "" "" "" ""` is completely similar to `eval foo`, no matter what `IFS` or other thing is.

Comment: @Kusalananda I agree that it is no problem here, if `$BCKGRND` is either `&` or nothing. As the asker is a new user, I would be extra careful. @David: Nothing against you, but you should always think twice before using `eval`. That applies to me too :-).

Comment: This answer was useful and probably the simplest way.  I almost marked it as the "winner" - but the other answer is actually closer to what I ended up choosing to do.  And thanks to @Ralf for the link about eval.  Was a good read.

Comment: The command being eval'ed should be in double quotes if it contains any special characters, e.g. `eval 'sleep $TIMEOUT' "$BACKGROUND"`. Otherwise you could get double expansions if the variable expands to another variable or contains special characters. Also, nested quoting can get tricky.